# no core dump generated for systemd service

Tags: systemd, coredump

I want to enable core dump generation for a systemd service which gives a SEGV status and exits.

> scd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
>
> Unit scd.service entered failed state.
>
> scd.service failed.

my bashrc file already has ulimit -c unlimited.

after running **systemd-coredumpctl** the output is

> No coredumps found.

Note : I am able to generate core dump for normal programs executed via terminal but unable to do so for a systemd service

Comment: Just to clarify you need to set LimitCORE=Infinity in your service file (scd.service), not your bashrc

Comment: Thank you your suggestion worked

Comment: i'll add a answer so you can put a accept the answer, that way other people with the same question can see this has been answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set `LimitCORE=infinity` in your service file (scd.service), not your bashrc.

More info in https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20Properties